# Copy Collection if I concrete type unknown

Tags: java, collections

I have a Collection object in runtime and I need to proxy each elements in collections and return the same collection without modifying existing collection. So I need to create instance with same type and fill it by proxied objects.
Can someone suggest approach how to do it without writing many instanceof?

UPD

```
           if (originalResult instanceof Collection) {
                Collection collection = ((Collection) originalResult);

                Collection newCollection = (Collection) collection.stream()
                        .map(this::proxyObject)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                collection.clear();
                collection.addAll(newCollection);
                return collection;

            } else if
```

This is part of code for my implementation of  ***net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor#intercept***
that after the call "get" methods return proxy. This was my first variant but I realized that this way does not suit for me because mutate the existing object.

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you have done so far in code?

Comment: If possible please share the code with some example explaining it. This is very vague statement

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran in general question quite simple and doesn't need any context, How no create the same instance of existing collection without instanceof, maybe I can use some lib?

Comment: “return the same collection without modifying existing collection” is a contradiction in itself. Do you mean “return a new collection of the same type?”.

Comment: @Holger "return a new collection of the same type?" exactly.

Comment: @Holger Actually I decided to use no-args constructor through reflection. I know that it will not work for some collections but now I can put up with it.